# Laravel: How to redirect after controller method execution

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-blade

**`web.php`:**

```
Route::post('caption/{id}/delete', 'DetailController@deleteCaption');
```

**`DetailController.php`:**

```
public function deleteCaption(Request $request, $id) {
    $caption = Caption::findOrFail($id);
    $caption->delete(); //doesn't delete permanently

    return response(204);
}
```

**`admin.blade.php`:**

```
<p value='{{$caption->id}}'>{{$caption->content}}</p>
<form action="caption/{{$caption->id}}/delete" method="post">
<button type="submit">Delete caption</button>
</form> 
<form action="caption/{{$caption->id}}/approve" method="post">
<button type="submit">Accept caption</button>
</form>
```

I want to make it so that after I delete an image, the user is redirected back to the admin page, located at localhost:8000/admin.

How can I do this? Documentation isn't understandable to me.

Comment: `return redirect('admin');` or `return redirect('path_to_admin');`

Comment: See second last row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can redirect like

```
public function deleteCaption(Request $request, $id) {
    $caption = Caption::findOrFail($id);
    $caption->delete(); //doesn't delete permanently

    return redirect()->to('link/to/anywhere');
}
```

OR 
You can redirect like this

```
return redirect()->back();
```

to your last state.

OR

```
return route('yourRouteName');
//if there's parameters
return route('yourRouteName', ['id' => 1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply redirect to your defined route in your web.php:

```
public function deleteCaption(Request $request, $id) {
    $caption = Caption::findOrFail($id);
    $caption->delete(); //doesn't delete permanently

    return redirect('admin');
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#redirects

Checking out the routing and blade docs may assist as well.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to return back to the same page. You can use Laravel's back function.

```
 return back();
```

To redirect user back to the page it came from.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect back use

```
return redirect()->back();
```

To redirect to specific route use

```
return return redirect()->route('route-name');
```