# Laravel redirect after destroy in resourceful controller

Tags: laravel

I'd like to redirect to a page after deleting an item. I've read multiple posts on this, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061040/laravel-how-to-redirect-after-controller-method-execution/43061660), but it doesn't seem to work.

What currently happens after pressing the delete button is that it lands on the show page and that gives a **404**. That's because the item is actually deleted so the page doesn't work anymore. But as per my code, after deleting it should redirect to the route `trade.index`.

**In routes/web**

```
Route::resource('/trade', 'TradeController');
```

**In TradeController**

```php
public function destroy($id)
{
    $trade = Trade::findOrFail($id);
    $trade->delete();
    return redirect()->route('trade.index')->with('success', 'Trade deleted');
}
```

**In the view**

```php
<form action="{{ route('trade.destroy', $trade->id) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block btn-animate" type="submit">
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete
    </button>
</form>
```

**From route:list**

```
DELETE | trade/{trade} | trade.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\TradeController@destroy                                
 | web,auth:web
```

What am I missing?

**Update based on some answers below**

First, if you create a resourceful controller through artisan like this

```
php artisan make:controller TradeController -r
```

Laravel generates this function in that controller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
     //
}
```

So that does make me think that using it with `$id` should work?

I've also ran

```
config:clear
```

and

```
cache:clear
```

to be sure. The weird thing is that my original code as posted above now sometimes work (it deletes and redirects correctly) and then after a few times it doesn't work (it does delete, but the redirect doesn't work). That's the same if I use `route('trade.destroy', ['id' => $trade->id])`.

Another thing is, for show() I use the same principe. Route used in view:

```
route('trade.show', $trade->id)
```

**Method in controller:**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $data = array(
        'trade'     => Trade::findOrFail($id),
    );
    return view('trade.show')->with($data);
}
```

If I use the below as per one of the answers, it still doesn't work.

```
public function destroy(Trade $trade)
{
    $trade->delete();
    return redirect()->route('trade.index')->with('success', 'Trade deleted');
}
```

Comment: findOrFail() could return a 404 response.

Comment: Can you post `php artisan route:list` output?

Comment: @dparoli I guess not because the trade is actually deleted. If that returns a 404 then the `->delete()` would never happen, right? As indicate the delete action is performed correctly, it's just that the redirect doesn't happen. @mdexp I've added the route:list result for the destroy action.

Comment: sorry if I insist but can you try to put dd($trade) after findOrFail($id) to see if the app arrive at the dd()?

Comment: Just change the form opening Tag action to:   route('trade.destroy', ['id' => $trade->id])

Comment: and delete function to:   optional(Trade::find($id))->delete();

Comment: The opening Form tag should be `route('trade.destroy', ['trade' => $trade->id])` because the route parameter name is `trade`. But `route('trade.destroy', $trade->id)` as the OP posted works the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your **route parameter name** is `{trade}` so you cannot use `$id` as **injected variabe** in the controller function.

You should use `$trade` to match the **route parameter name** or the `findOrFail()` function would be unable to find anything because `$id` is `null`, i.e.:

```php
public function destroy($trade)
{
    $trade = Trade::findOrFail($trade);
    $trade->delete();
    return redirect()->route('trade.index')->with('success', 'Trade deleted');
}
```

Or even better with **implicit model binding**:

```php
public function destroy(Trade $trade)
{
    $trade->delete();
    return redirect()->route('trade.index')->with('success', 'Trade deleted');
}
```

You can read the laravel docs about implicit binding [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding).

Comment: please consider accepting and upvoting the answer if it solves your problem

Comment: `Your route parameter name is {trade} so you cannot use $id as injected variabe in the controller function.` I might be wrong, but if I recall correctly, I think that if you don't need implicit binding the argument can be named anything you want (but must not be type-hinted). However if you do want to use implicit model binding you have to match the route parameter's name with the function argument name and type-hint the model, as you said

Comment: Probably @mdexp you're right, I didnt try by myself, I have the habit to give the same name to parameter and injected variable just to not have problems

Comment: Yeah, I do that as well, to me is indeed nicer and more readable

Comment: @dparoli this doesn't seem to work. I've updated my answer.

Comment: You should have some other problem, the only way now is to debug each step with dd()

Answer (score 0):

From your `php artisan route:list` run result

```
DELETE | trade/{trade} | trade.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\TradeController@destroy | web,auth:web
```

The parameter passed to your `destroy()` method should be bound to a model named `trade`. So you have to setup ***route model binding*** for this.

First go to the following file:

```
app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php
```

and include model bindings in your `boot()` method if it isn't present

**RouteServiceProvider.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Trade;
use Illuminate\Support\Facade\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        Route::model('trade', Trade::class); // model binding
    }
}
```

Then, you can now define your delete route method properly

```php
public function destroy(Trade $trade)
{
    $trade->delete();
    return redirect()->route('trade.index')->with('success', 'Trade deleted');
}
```

Comment: Explicit binding is unneeded, implicit binding with the type-hinted variable is more then enough and the match is not between the parameter name and the model name but between the parameter name and the type-hinted variable name.

Comment: "include model bindings in your boot() method **if** it isn't present". If the binding isn't present the `destroy(Trade $trade)` won't work. But `destroy($trade)` would work if `route::list` had specified `trade/{id}`. So the down vote isn't necessary.

Comment: "Your delete function is expecting an object of class Trade" this part is absolutely false and misleading this is the reason for the downvote. you shou read carefully the link in my answer about implicit binding. The 90% of problems with implicit binding in laravel are because people think that the parameter name should match the model name but it should match instead the type hinted variable name.

Comment: Implicit binding still works if the route parameter is named the same as the controller's type-hinted argument, and the controller type-hinted class will be used to retrive the model instance

Comment: @dparoli, ok I'll remove that part. But I don't think the past parameter should match the name. What I think is the name of the parameter included in route definition should match that in the model binding. `destroy(Trade $anything)` is very valid.

Comment: destroy(Trade $anything) does not work because "trade" is the parameter name. From the laravel docs I linked above: "Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route segment name."

Comment: @dparoli, From the documentation: implicit binding (with type hinting) - `Route::get('delete/{trade}', function (App\Trade $trade) { });`. But the asker has a resource route.

Comment: Yes in fact the route parameter name is 'trade' from the destroy route the OP posted. But you can try by yourself with a resource controller implicit binding works the same